# php spark serve Codeigniter 4 not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I installed library from endroid's github (qr-code).
When i was trying to do php spark serve, it said:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to CodeIgniter\CLI\Console::_
_construct() must be an instance of CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter, int given, called i
n D:\Kuliah\Magang\akses-log-data-center-itb\spark on line 49 and defined in D:\
Kuliah\Magang\akses-log-data-center-itb\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\CLI
\Console.php:29
Stack trace:
#0 D:\Kuliah\Magang\akses-log-data-center-itb\spark(49): CodeIgniter\CLI\Console
->__construct(1)
#1 {main}
  thrown in D:\Kuliah\Magang\akses-log-data-center-itb\vendor\codeigniter4\frame
work\system\CLI\Console.php on line 29
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: What have you tried to figure out this problem, yourself? Have you done any research? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this

> copy the index.php file in vendor/codeigniter4/framework/public/index.php (to) public/index.php

then

> copy spark file in vendor/codeigniter4/framework/spark (to) root folder

from:
https://forum.codeigniter.com/printthread.php?tid=82087

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This solution worked for me @Community your algorithm needs to be updated. The instruction was clear and precise.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to [Brian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72854231/8087608), I found out that the spark file was updated in version 4.2.0. If you have experienced this issue, I suggest you read its [changelog](https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/installation/upgrade_420.html) to learn about other breaking changes.